# Protractor Async call issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I am new to protractor. Intially when building my code i used multiple its but then I moved everything in one it and now my code looks like this :

```
var UI = require('./../ui.js');
var co = require('co');
var ui = new UI();

describe("MapFeedback: address-no longer exists", function() {
    ui.setSmallScreenSize();
    // ui.testLogger(100);
    it("test", co.wrap(function*() {
        yield browser.get(ui.createStartLink());
        yield ui.PLACE_PROBLEM.click();
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("report_place");
        yield ui.REPORT_PLACE_INAPPROPRITATE.click();
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("select_place_content/place_content");

        yield ui.zoomIn(18.5);
        //its clicking the way to early before the zoomIn is performed.

        var elmOK = element(By.css('button[ng-click="doneSelectObject(selectedObject)"]'));
        yield ui.waitFor(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elmOK));
        yield elmOK.click();

        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("place_content");
        yield ui.RADIOBOX_OTHER.click();
        yield ui.TEXTBOX_PLACE_DETAILS.sendKeys('TEST');
        yield ui.SUBMIT.click();
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("submit");
        yield ui.waitSubmit();
        expect(yield element(By.css('div[ng-show="mapFeedBack.submitState==\'success\'"]')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
    }));
});
```

but somehow when I run my code I get this error and I don't know how to fix it.

```
1) MapFeedback: address-no longer exists test                                                                                                                                          
  Message:                                                                                                                                                                             
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.                                                                      
  Stack:                                                                                                                                                                               
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.                                                                      
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:224:11)                                                                                                                                             
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:198:5)                                                                                                                                       

1 spec, 1 failure                                                                                                                                                                      
Finished in 30.831 seconds                                                                                                                                                             
[15:18:24] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running                                                                                                                       
[15:18:24] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)                                                                                                                                    
[15:18:24] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)                                                                                                                                      
Closing report                                                                                                                                                                         
[15:18:24] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

How can I ensure that the later code runs only after the ui.zoomin() is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You will see error when Jasmine timeout's before the complete execution is done

Either increase the timeout setting in protractor conf.js

```
 timeout: 50000,
```

Or if you want to do the timeout change only for this spec

```
  this.timeout(50000);
```

And to ensure that the later part of code runs only after `UI.zoomin()` is completed, it depends on the whether `UI.zoomin()` returns a promise/callback. If so then the subsequent commands must be chained

If `UI.zoomin()` contains webdriverJs commands, they they will automatically placed into the webdriver control flow.